# Reduce the big size of my Android application resource

Tags: java, android, file, compression, libsvm

I am currently developing an android application that use`Libsvm library` for data

classification.

To use  the  `Libsvm` I should provide file text describing data

the size of my data=1,3G

I have placed all my files in assets Folder => copied them in sdCard and then running the

classification

The problem Now is that my application take a lot of time to be installed on my device!

It is possible to compress those files and the decompress them while running my

classification?

And How to do this in Android

Comment: Hmm, more accurately this would be reducing the size of an application resource, not so much the application itself. Come to think of it, can you supply the library with a resource or stream of some kind? In that case you could include it with compressed byte code.

Answer (score 1):

move your resources to desktop and delete them from your app, this would be helpful for testing your app.

Answer (score 0):

You could zip the file on the installation and make your service unzips it the first time it's used.

You may zip/unzip using the java.util.zip standard package.

Comment: yes i find a tutorial speak about this package I will try it now but I have a question , what'is the percentage of compression ??

Comment: @nawara test it using some zipping application that provides several levels of compression, if it is text-like then it should compress really well.

Comment: @owlstead..I should compress my text files before put them in assets folders??

And then how to decompress them and is there o lost of information?